# open file O_NONBLOCKING gets lost in kernel module

Tags: c, file-io, blocking, kernel-module

I am opening a file in my C program:

```
pcm->dfd = open(fname, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
```

and later call `select()` and `read()` on it.

But my problem is, that the `O_NONBLOCK` gets lost somewere:

```
ssize_t my_read(struct file *filp, char __user *user_buffer, size_t bytes_requested, loff_t *capture_ptr) {

    if (filp->f_flags & O_NONBLOCK){
        LOGI("mode: O_NONBLOCK");
    }
    else{
        LOGI("mode: BLOCKING"); // <-- this is printed      
    }
    ..
}
```

I also tried

```
pcm->dfd=open(fname, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);

// O_NONBLOCK does not work :/
int flags = fcntl(pcm->dfd, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(pcm->dfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

It's not a logging-problem, the driver also behaves as in blocking-mode.

Anyone an idea?

EDIT:

The code which reads from the opened file is absolutely simple:

```
size=read(pcm->dfd,inBuffer,inBufferBytes);
```

I also checked the program if there's a `fcntl()` somewere else, but no..

EDIT 2:

May it be possible, that the `O_NONBLOCK` has an other value in my user-program (Android NDK) than in the kernel? I searched for `O_NONBLOCK` in the kernel-headers and already there are 2 different definitions.

I also checked the `open`-implementation in my kernel module and already there `filp->f_flags` is **not** `O_NONBLOCK`.

Comment: Show us the code performing the `read`.

Comment: Opening files with `O_NONBLOCK` results in UB (a.k.a. _unspecified behaviour_) as per [the specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/open.html).

Comment: Yes, sure, but I'm the developer of the opened file (kernel module) and can control what happens.. but the information "O_NONBLOCK" is no more available to me as described above.

Comment: Is this a regular file in a regular file system, a regular file on a special file system (like /sys or /proc), or a device file?

Comment: The .ko is under `/data/data/myDevice.ko` (internal android-storage) and after `insmod` my character-device is under `/dev/myDevice`. The C-file which opens `/dev/myDevice` is in the same directory as the .ko-file. I think this should be the same file system.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the "file" that you are trying to open with `O_NONBLOCK` is in fact a *character device*.  Contra what several other people have said, it *is* valid and well-defined to open character devices with `O_NONBLOCK`, provided the driver supports it.  Can you show your `open` implementation, your module initialization function, and your `chrdev_ops` structure please?

Comment: Something fishy is definitely going on if it's not making it to your driver's `open()` routine with `O_NONBLOCK` set.  It should definitely be making it there. :-/

Comment: how about calling open twice- once with O_NONBLOCK and once without. Both the times, log the entire filp->f_flags variable. this should tell us which bits(if any) are being toggled.

Comment: Did you find any solutions, yet?

Comment: Hi, sadly I had to stop the developments on this problem. After a kernel-update there where several new problems for which I haven't got any more nerves & time. But finally, no, this problem is unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

According to [open(2) man-page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=open&sektion=2), passing `O_NONBLOCK` only makes the `open` call itself non-blocking (which you, probably, don't want). It does not imply, that the opened file descriptor will also be in non-blocking mode -- you have to set that with a fcntl() after opening.